# Trying to change button text in a view from an appDelegate method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm a little new to iOS development and am running into a little problem.

I've implemented the FB SDK for iOS login into my app, and I can login and out no problem.

However, what I'm trying to do is change the single button text from 'Log in' to 'Log out', depending on the state of the FB session.

In my appDelegate (which handles the FB session state changes), I'm calling two methods from my main view controller like this:

```
helloappViewController * vc = [[helloappViewController alloc]init];
[vc showLogInButton];
```

...and...

```
helloappViewController * vc = [[helloappViewController alloc]init];
[vc showLogOutButton];
```

The methods in `helloappViewController` that are being called are these:

```
- (void) showLogInButton {
    NSLog(@"Changing button text to 'Login'.");
    [self.buttonLogInLogOut setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}


- (void) showLogOutButton {
    NSLog(@"Changing button text to 'Logout'.");
    [self.buttonLogInLogOut setTitle:@"Logout" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I know these methods is being called properly because I can see the console log output fine, and I know I'm logged in and out via FB because of other console log outputs I've set.

However, the button title text is not being changed.

Anyone have any idea where I might be going wrong?

Thx.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: are you sure you are making connections to the buttons ?

Comment: Yes, I had connected the button to the view in IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move code

```
[self showLogInButton];
```

and

```
[self showLogOutButton];
```

to viewDidLoad method of the helloappViewController view controller

something like this:

```
helloappViewController * vc = [[helloappViewController alloc]init];
vc.fbIsConnected = YES;
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
if (self.fbIsConnect)
{
    [self showLogOutButton];
}
else
{
    [self showLogInButton];
}
```

In vc:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(fbDidChange)
                                             name: FBDidChangeNotification
                                           object: nil];
- (void) fbDidChange
{
// change button title
}
```

in fb controller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FBDidChangeNotification object:self];
```

Comment: Additionally, I'm already calling these in the viewDidAppear method when the app first loads so the correct button is set and this works fine. The problem I'm having is that call these methods from the appDelegate ain't working for me.

Comment: What I need to do is change the button text on the fly depending on the FB session state change. This will only change the button text on first load of the view (the app is a single view app). I guess what I'm having problems with is that maybe I'm not referencing the button properly in the `showLogOutButton` and `showLogInButton` methods?

Comment: you can use NSNotificationCenter for notification your vc about change state of the fb

Comment: better check you FB session state inside you ViewController _fbIsLoggedIn = FBSession.activeSession.isOpen; and change your button text depending of this state.

Comment: OK, but is there some kind of listener for notifications?

Comment: @Eugene Prokoshev: how do I tell the ViewController that there has been a change of session state?

Comment: @stosha Brilliant. I've used NSNotificationCenter to do this and it works as I need it to. Thanks for the help.